# Is setting a Javascript event on the whole document worse than multiple individual events?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, dom

On a standard webpage you have hundreds (or thousands) of DOMNodes. When building single-page applications (or angular/react/polymer based projects) almost every link or button is already click-jacked by the framework using custom events to bind the DOMElement to a handler function.

So, since you can [bind the whole document](http://jsfiddle.net/Xeoncross/pv4nzy3w/2/) to a click event (and then check the `event.target`) would that be a more performant way to listen for lots of events?

Or is setting dozens of `click` handlers still better?

```
function report(event) {
    console.log(event.target, event);
    return false; // You would only want to return false if you actually wanted to intercept this event (and the user wasn't pressing ctrl/cmd+click).
}

document
    .addEventListener('click', report, true);

// vs
document.querySelector('.a')
    .addEventListener('click', report, true);
document.querySelector('.b')
    .addEventListener('click', report, true);
document.querySelector('.c')
    .addEventListener('click', report, true);
```

More performant can mean less CPU cycles or less memory or both.

Comment: It's definitely "better", for certain values of "better"... But seriously, you don't necessarily need to add a lot of boilerplate code to make it work. You could define a couple of general event helper functions that map events to appropriate callbacks via the one general document-level click handler. Sometimes it's definitely easier to bind at the element level though, especially if you plan to sometimes cancel even propagation, etc.

Comment: This cannot be answered

Comment: @happy, why not? I just wanted an answer about this theory before I spent a couple hours rigging up a test page with hundreds of elements and testing performance across multiple browsers.

Comment: In my experience the opposite is true: attaching a big top-level event handler tends to consume less memory than per-element handlers. Speed-wise I didn't notice a difference. This was on an application with thousands of clilckable nodes (a family tree)

Comment: @Xeoncross because it is subject to interpretation. Even your experimentation result will be subject to interpretation. Imo

Comment: @happy, please provide more details. Do you mean different browsers may have faster implementations of event bubbling/catching or what? Seems like a pretty standard question: bind to document vs bind to each element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple reasons binding to the document (called event delegation) is better:

1. There are fewer instances of the event handler in memory. If you have very large numbers of items, this will save memory
2. There is a smaller chance of memory leaks for event handlers that do not get unregistered properly when elements are deleted
3. There is less work that has to happen every time you add a new element of the type that should respond to the event handler - hence less CPU usage

Depending on the application, the delegated event handler might have to do more work to figure out how to process the event properly for each individual instance, whereas the individual handlers can use the scope to store values for use inside the handler itself - this might be quicker.

So the answer depends on your application